# How to display JSON Array in Blade view?

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-5

[My db table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17iPp.png)

I'm using a view composer to get data from this table and send it back to my view

```
class NavComposer
{

 public function compose(View $view)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $view->with('unread_notifications', DB::table('notifications')->where([
                                            ['read_at', '=', NULL],
                                            ['notifiable_id', '=', Auth::user()->id],
                                            ])->get());
        }
    }
}
```

My view:

```
@foreach($unread_notifications as $notification)
{{ $notification->data }}
@endforeach
```

What I am getting:

```
{"id":79,"sender":"Diana","receiver":"Alex","subject":"Subject","body":"Lorem ipsum"}
```

What I want to display:

```
ID: 79
Subject: Subject
Body: Lorem Ipsum
```

I apologize in advance if this is very simple stuff I dont know much about JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to decode JSON. You can do this manually:

```
@foreach($unread_notifications as $notification)
    <?php $notificationData = json_decode($notification->data, true); ?>
    {{ $notificationData['sender'] }}
@endforeach
```

Or you can [create accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) so Laravel could automatically convert JSON to an array:

```
public function getDataAttribute($value)
{
    return json_decode($value, true);
}
```

Comment: This did it!! Thank you very much ^_^

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach($unread_notifications as $notification)
   @foreach(json_decode($notification->data, true) as $d)
      <div>ID: {{ $d['id'] }}</div>
      <div>Subject: {{ $d['subject'] }}</div>
      <div>Body: {{ $d['body'] }}</div>
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I get error: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: @rmdy, Answer modified.